# problem with validation link -php

Tags: php, validation

i have this link:

```
http://localhost/login/activation.php?usermail=xxxxx@gmail.com?usercode=$P$Bs9FpyKdKVFdVXYJ6dZCfcZqzWHLlc/
```

but this validation return Bad request. Why?

```
  function checkBd() {
        if (empty($_GET['usermail']) || (empty($_GET['usercode']))) {
            echo "Bad request<br/>";
            return false;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: It may be because of the `$` or `/` character in the URL.

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump $_GET?

Comment: are you missing the & characters? should it not look something like this 

http://localhost/login/activation.php?usermail=xxxxx@gmail.com&usercode=$P$Bs9FpyKdKVFdVXYJ6dZCfcZqzWHLlc/

Comment: if i do only: if (empty($_GET['usermail'])) { the code works well

Comment: @martswite is right, I didn't notice that.  `?usercode=` should be `&usercode=`.

Comment: @rocket, totally correct, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you missing the & characters? should it not look something like this

```
http://localhost/login/activation.php?usermail=xxxxx@gmail.com&usercode=$P$Bs9FpyKdKVFdVXYJ6dZCfcZqzWHLlc/
```

I guess its currently taking everything after ?usermail to be one parameter?

Comment: @Rocket I fudged it when copying and pasting it... don't know how. I fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
http://localhost/login/activation.php?usermail=xxxxx@gmail.com&usercode=$P$Bs9FpyKdKVFdVXYJ6dZCfcZqzWHLlc/
```

I changed the second "?" to "&" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have got `?` twice in there.Fix it and it should be aright.

Edit:
Right now you GET var looks something like this because of the second `?` in the url.

```
Array ( [usermail] => xxxxx@gmail.com?usercode=$P$Bs9FpyKdKVFdVXYJ6dZCfcZqzWHLlc/ )
```